# Rails: Trying to separate a model into an engine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-models

I'm new to here an to Rails so excuse any dumbness on my part.

I'm trying to do something really simple and can't seen to find a guide that's up to date and properly demonstrates how to do this.

I've written the app described in the official ruby on rails tutorial:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Now I want to take one of the models, say Tags and make a gem out of that. How would I achieve this? I've read some on rails Engines but couldn't really figure out what goes where and mostly what the generators would look like.

I want to be able to write another app now, such as something flickr styled and by adding the new Tags gem to the Gemfile and having a

```
:has_many tags
```

In the picture model I've added a tags mechanism to all my pictures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Glad you liked the getting started guide, I then shall guide you to the (yet unreleased) [engines guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

Comment: Thank you! That was incredibly helpful!
Now I need to figure out how to get access to tags belonging to a post in it's view. I tried @post.<namespace>_tags.build and that doesn't seem to work. If there's a simple solution I'd love to hear it :)